# BaseAdapter class methods need to be called explicitly?

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I am trying to create a dynamic listview using BaseAdapter class. For that I have extended the BaseAdapter class into one custom adapter class. I have implemented all the default methods for BaseAdapter like getCount(), getItem(), getView() etc.

Now while calling the custom base adapter class, it is only executing the constructor within that class. The methods are not getting invoked.

When I explicitly call the methods individiually then things are working.

Below are my code for custom base adapter class:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public Context ba_context;
public ArrayList<String> listitem = new ArrayList<>();
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyBaseAdapter(Context ma_context, ArrayList<String> ma_listitem) {
    super();
    this.ba_context = ma_context;
    this.listitem = ma_listitem;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) ba_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.listitem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.listitem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long) position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_layout,parent,false);

    TextView carrier = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_textview1);
    TextView number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_textview2);
    TextView arrivaltime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_textview6);
    TextView departuretime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_textview7);
    TextView saletotal = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_textview8);

    String str_carrier = listitem.get(position).toString();
    String str_number = listitem.get(position).toString();
    String str_arrivaltime = listitem.get(position).toString();
    String str_departuretime = listitem.get(position).toString();
    String str_saletotal = listitem.get(position).toString();

    carrier.setText(str_carrier);
    number.setText(str_number);
    arrivaltime.setText(str_arrivaltime);
    departuretime.setText(str_departuretime);
    saletotal.setText(str_saletotal);

    return vi;
}
```

}

The portion of Main Activity class is:

```
MyBaseAdapter baseAdapter = new               MyBaseAdapter(context,listitem);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
```

If I explicitly call them then it works. Like below --

```
int listitem_size = baseAdapter.getCount();
```

MY QUESTION IS: 
1. According to what I have read before, these methods are always implicitly called. Then why it is not working for me.
2. Can I still proceed with my work, doing this explicit call?

Please help me out!

---

Editted Part
Adding the ListView layout xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
tools:context="saumikbhattacharya.FlightSearch.com.DisplayFlightsActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

The code for Main Activity is here:

```
public class DisplayFlightsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String str_jsonresponse,fare,carrier,number,arrivaltime,departuretime,origin,destination;

ArrayList<String> listitem = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listView;
//MyBaseAdapter baseAdapter;
Context context = DisplayFlightsActivity.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
str_jsonresponse = extras.getString(DisplaySummaryActivity.STR_JSONRESPONSE);

try{
    JSONObject root_jsonresponse = new JSONObject(str_jsonresponse);
    JSONObject l1_jsonobject = root_jsonresponse.optJSONObject("trips");
    JSONArray l2_jsonarray = l1_jsonobject.optJSONArray("tripOption");
    for (int i=0;i < l2_jsonarray.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject l21_jsonobject = l2_jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        fare = l21_jsonobject.getString("saleTotal");
        JSONArray l3_jsonarray = l21_jsonobject.optJSONArray("slice");
        for (int j=0;j < l3_jsonarray.length();j++)
        {
            JSONObject l4_jsonobject = l3_jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);
            JSONArray l5_jsonarray = l4_jsonobject.optJSONArray("segment");
            for(int k=0;k < l5_jsonarray.length();k++)
            {
                JSONObject l6_jsonobject = l5_jsonarray.getJSONObject(k);
                JSONObject l7_jsonobject = l6_jsonobject.optJSONObject("flight");
                carrier = l7_jsonobject.getString("carrier");
                number = l7_jsonobject.getString("number");
                JSONArray l8_jsonarray = l6_jsonobject.optJSONArray("leg");
                for(int m=0;m < l8_jsonarray.length(); m++)
                {
                    JSONObject l9_jsonobject = l8_jsonarray.getJSONObject(m);
                    arrivaltime = l9_jsonobject.getString("arrivalTime");
                    departuretime = l9_jsonobject.getString("departureTime");
                    origin = l9_jsonobject.getString("origin");
                    destination = l9_jsonobject.getString("destination");
                }
            }
        }
        listitem.add(fare);
        listitem.add(carrier);
        listitem.add(number);
        listitem.add(arrivaltime);
        listitem.add(departuretime);
        listitem.add(origin);
        listitem.add(destination);
    }
}
catch(JSONException JE){
    JE.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception err){
    err.printStackTrace();
}

MyBaseAdapter baseAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(context,listitem);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);

setTitle("Results Page");
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_flights);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you set listview height as `wrap_content`?

Comment: Everything looks OK. Can you see your listView on your user interface?

Comment: What do you mean by not working for you? What do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: @Prasad -- No I have tried setting match_parent and fill_parent

Comment: @innoSPG -- it is just executing the constructor and the control is coming back to the main activity. It is not invoking the methods that I have mentioned. The listview on UI is coming as blank.

Comment: The call to those methods are implicit when drawing and updating the listView. So if you have some data in `ma_listitem`, it should work. Show you layout file.

Comment: @innoSPG -- This is my ListView layout.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    tools:context="saumikbhattacharya.FlightSearch.com.DisplayFlightsActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: @innoSPG --  I have added the layout xml properly in the Question. Please help me out.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner I have checked your code and its working. getCount(), getItem(), getView() methods are called implicitly.

Comment: :) Then why I am not getting proper results? Did you check the code inside those methods? @DurgeshPatel

Comment: I was actually asking for listview_item_layout xml. I can see that @DurgeshPatel gave some suggestions. Try it and come back if it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played with your code. Please look at below code.

Below code goes inside `onCreate()` of your Activity :

```
ArrayList<String> listitem = new ArrayList<String>();
listitem.add("ABC");
listitem.add("DEF");

MyBaseAdapter baseAdapter = new  MyBaseAdapter(this,listitem);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
```

Below code is for BaseAdapter implementation :

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public Context ba_context;
    public ArrayList<String> listitem = new ArrayList<String>();
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyBaseAdapter(Context ma_context, ArrayList<String> ma_listitem) {
        super();
        this.ba_context = ma_context;
        this.listitem = ma_listitem;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ba_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e("MyBaseAdapter", "getCount() => " + this.listitem.size());
        return this.listitem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.listitem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (long) position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        Log.i("MyBaseAdapter", "String=>" + this.listitem.get(position).toString());
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_layout, parent, false);

        TextView tvData = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvData);

        String data = listitem.get(position).toString();

        tvData.setText(data);

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Run your application

Look at your LogCat and you will find log which is written for `getCount()` that is called implicitly by Android OS.

Find below `listview_item_layout.xml` file which i used for my example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView  android:id="@+id/tvData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="data"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you @Durgesh Patel ! I can see that you have just added a Log statement inside my code. There is no other changes you have made. I will try this and will keep you updated. :)

Comment: @AndroidBeginner okay.. buddy... looking for your feedback and update.

Comment: Hi @Durgesh! Sorry for the late reply. I have investigated some more and found that when I am trying to find the listview from the xml, it is returning null value. This step is returning null value. 
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
I have attached the Main Activity code also in the question. Please have a look. :) Thanks.

Comment: After some more investigation I was able to resolve the listview null issue. I have placed the setContentView before findViewbyId statement and it worked after that. Now I can see a listview populated with data coming in from the JSON. :) After so many trials, I am glad that the basic code worked. :) Still the data in the listview is not consistent, not showing properly, but yes something is better than nothing. I will check that. Thank you all for your feedback. :)

Comment: @AndroidBeginner if you satisfied with my feedback/answer, please accept this answer :)